# Specialize an enum

Tags: c++, enums

How to specialize an `enum` in modern C++?

I found out that it is possible not only to provide specializations for methods but also for enumerations. The caveat is to use either based enums or provide a dummy enumerator with a value equal to the maximum value provided by any of the specializations. This makes sense to me as there might be other members that depend on the enumeration's underlying type size.

The example below works fine as long as the template class is declared as a `struct`. As soon as I declare it to be a `class` the enumerators provided in the specializations become inaccessible:

```
test.cc: In function 'int main()':
test.cc:27:20: error: 'Class<3>::Enum Item' is private within this context
  int x = Class<3>::Item;
```

How to resolve this?

### SSCCE

```
template<int i>
struct Class {
public:
    enum Enum {
        // Stretch underlying type (alternatively: use based enum)
        MaxBit = 100
    };

    enum EnumAlternative: int {
        // Like this
    };
};

template<>
enum Class<2>::Enum {
    Item = 12
};

template<>
enum Class<3>::Enum {
    Item = 42
};


int main() {
    int x = Class<3>::Item; // Line 27
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a GCC extension rather than standard C++.

Comment: Trusting GCC, it seemed to become standard C++ with C++11 and fails to compiler with C++03.

Comment: Normally when you specialize a class that means that you need to define its contents independent of the template class, e.g. there is not `Class<2>::Enum` in your code unless you define `template<> class Class<2> {}` to contain it.

Comment: @Kamajii Try compiling with `-pedantic`.

Comment: @TartanLlama: You're right, it complains with a warning when compiling with `-pedantic` :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the specialization of your `Class` to **contain** your `Enum`

```
template<>
class Class<2>
{
public:
    enum Enum
    {
        Item = 12
    };
};

int main() 
{
    int x = Class<2>::Item; // x with 12
}
```

Now that we have [constexpr variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) since C++11, consider using that.

Comment: But then I inherently loose any other members of the unspecialized class (if any), right?

Comment: @Kamajii Yes, but there is no way to partially specialize `enum` only. I am sure you can work around that in a way.